# jQuery temporary alert messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create some sort of temporary alert messages using jQuery so a alert message appears (a div with some style and a message ) and then after X seconds dissapear.

If the user clicks again the alert will appear again...

Currently my script is not even removing the alerts. Removing the temp_alert_X name to temp_alert will make them dissapear after X seconds but then if the user clicks again on the button the alert wont come out again until refresh..

```
function createFarm(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/new_farm.php",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        if(data.error == 1){

            $('.sidebar_frame').append("<p><div id='alert_error' class='temp_alert_" + new_farm_error + "'> " +  data.log + "</div></p>")
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.temp_alert_' + new_farm_error + '').remove()
            }, 200)

            new_farm_error++;

        }else{}

    }).fail(function() {
            alert( "Error while creating new farm 404." );
    });
}
```

Note:

```
new_Farm_error = 0
```

Comment: Since you're giving your alert `<div>` an "id" value, why not just use that to refer to it?

Comment: Well if I remove by the alert_error I wont be able to create new alert_error divs with that id... dont know why but they wont pop-out

Comment: 200 milliseconds is a short time to show an alert... are you sure it's just not being hidden before you have time to see it?

Comment: Uhh no, there should be no problem; you're code is attempting to remove the element anyway. Also note that it doesn't make sense to put a `<div>` inside a `<p>` and the browser won't treat it that way. Just get rid of the surrounding `<p> ... </p>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these lines:

```
$('.sidebar_frame').append("<p><div id='alert_error' class='temp_alert_" + new_farm_error + "'> " +  data.log + "</div></p>")
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.temp_alert_' + new_farm_error + '').remove()
 }, 200)
```

with, these:

```
 var $errorMsg = $("<p><div id='alert_error' class='temp_alert_" + new_farm_error + "'> " +  data.log + "</div></p>");
 $('.sidebar_frame').append($errorMsg);
 setTimeout(function() {
     $errorMsg.remove();
 }, 200)
```

*note. 200 millisecond is a very short time.*

---

You don't need to parse JSON if you use `dataType : "json"`

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : "json"
    //...
});
```